# Python script does not run on crontab

Tags: python, cron

I want to run a `python` script periodically, so I use `crontab`. This is what my `crontab -e` looks like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python/2.7/site-packages /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python /Users/username/Desktop/processes/test.py
```

The `python` version I am using is downloaded from `home-brew`.

As I've seen in many cases, *I can run the `test.py` manually*, but `crontab -e` does not seem to work. I might have included extra things, but I don't think these should affect the output.

The error I get through `cat /var/mail/username` is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/processes/test.py”, line 34, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['bash', commands_txt_shortened]) # Run the txt file to retrieve the images.
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have noticed that you are running this function in every minute. And I guess you are trying to read a txt inside that function and processing read data. Maybe a started thread cannot finish in 1 minute and that's why upcoming cronjob cannot open the .txt so that raises an error?

Comment: @cengineer The first part you mentioned is right. Your 'maybe' part is that when the script runs it should create a folder and I can see that this folder is never created.

Comment: @cengineer Also, I've been told that if there are `print` statements in the script, this might cause a problem for `crontab -e`.

Comment: Okay so can you check you python @thanasissdr ? You can check it by 'which python' command. Output of this command should be the same '/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python'. Otherwise replace the '/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' in your cronjob by the output of the 'which python' command. If they are the same, let deep into the script

Comment: @cengineer Yes , that's the way it is.

Comment: I noticed that your `PATH` in crontab did not include `/bin` . Perhaps your script couldn't find the `bash` executable?

Comment: @ChangQian Thanks, I'll try that, as well.